# How can I construct a search query to yield the same content as the old Beginner tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, search

I have been struggling to do this since the tag was banned and would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Please note: I do not want this search to be language specific.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you want posts that are would be considered <kbd>beginner</kbd> questions?

The answer is you can't. One of the reasons meta tags where banned, especially the beginner tag, was because everybody's idea of what a beginner question is, is completely different, and the tag held no value for anyone really. It also had a bit of a negative connection to it, and some users found it insulting when their questions where tagged beginner.

Every tag so far that people have tried to use to replace <kbd>beginner</kbd> has since been banned as well, and chances are this will keep happening going forward.

Comment: Well ... considering I'm trying to duplicate the tag (others are as well), it clearly had value for some of us.

Comment: @timepilot, it probably didn't have the value you thought it did.

Comment: @Dour High Arch: Given that it takes me 3x the time to find less than a 1/3 of the content I used to be able to by just using the meta-tag, pls enlighten me.